# Laptop - UEFI / Fast Mode Issues

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, boot, bios

I just upgraded one of my Samsung laptop's to use Windows 10 from Windows 8. Before installation, I deleted all partitions on the Hard Drive in NTFS format - including the EFI partition!

During installation , something went wrong and now Windows is stuck in a boot loop.

I'm now unable to boot from my USB drive and unable to enter the BIOS settings - presumably Fast Mode is enabled?

Each time I go into the BIOS setup (F2), the laptop cycles it's power and hits a message stating "all boots options tried". Any ideas?

Comment: See https://www.easeus.com/partition-master/restore-repair-deleted-efi-boot-partition-in-windows-10-8-7.html and https://www.diskgenius.com/how-to/migrate-os-to-ssd.php

Comment: Why did you delete the EFI (BIOS) partition?  Perhaps contact Samsung and see if they can / will ship you a recovery USB key

Comment: Hi both - I've managed to get the HDD set up with a fresh Windows 10 image using my desktop pc. When plugging the HDD back into the laptop - I still get the all bolt options tried, any ideas?